# Can you explain why error "permissions denied" is a common problem with fish uninstall?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, fish, macos-big-sur

What does it mean to 'unlink file'? I keep discovering many Fish files and folders on my macOs (local, shared, HD volume). It seems the installation places Fish everywhere but despite being the only main user of my iMac, I still get "permissions denied" at every point where I try to remove the file/folder. What's the best approach to solve this and prevent permissions denied?

**Removing from Macintosh HD**

```
bolouie@Bos-iMac macintosh hd % rm -rf usr/local/etc/fish
```

**Output**

```
rm: usr/local/etc/fish/config.fish: Permission denied
rm: usr/local/etc/fish/completions: Permission denied
rm: usr/local/etc/fish/functions: Permission denied
rm: usr/local/etc/fish/conf.d: Permission denied
rm: usr/local/etc/fish: Directory not empty
```

**I try again with my system password**

```
bolouie@Bos-iMac macintosh hd % sudo rm -R/fish
```

**Output**

```
rm: illegal option -- /
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
unlink file
```

**how should I proceed?**

Answer (score 1):

A default fish install puts its files in `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/local/etc/`, and `/usr/local/share/`. Something like this will remove them:

```
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/bin/fish* /usr/local/etc/fish* /usr/local/share/fish*
```